# php form submit through basic authentication restfull api

Tags: php, json, web-services, http, header

Here i am trying to login a form using php and restfull webservices, when ever i am trying to execute it is poping up basic auth username and password. It has to communicate automatically, in my situation it is not happening any idea where am i going wrong?

```
 <?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $postData = array('userId'=>$_POST['userId'],'password'=> $_POST['password']);


    $authToken = base64_encode( "rest:rest" );

    // Setup cURL
    $ch = curl_init('http://xxxxxxxxxxx:8080/LIMS_Mobile/rest/loginpage/authenticate');
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Authorization: Basic'.$authToken,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        ),
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($postData)
    ));

    // Send the request
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    // Check for errors
    if($response === FALSE){
        die(curl_error($ch));
    }

    // Decode the response
    $responseData = json_decode($response, TRUE);

    // Print the date from the response
    print_r($responseData);




    if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
        echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
    }
    }
    ?>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form method="post" name="myForm" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="row">
    <div class= "form-group">
        <label class= "col-md-2"> UserId </label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <input name="userId"  type= "text" class= "form-control" placeholder="Your name" required/>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class= "form-group">
        <label class= "col-md-2"> Passeord </label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
       <input name="password" type= "text" class= "form-control" placeholder="Your name" required/>
         </div>
    </div>

    <div class= "form-group">
        <label class= "col-md-2"></label>
        <div class="col-md-4">

            <input type="submit" name="submit"/>

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use basic authentication with curl request you should use both the `CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH` and `CURLOPT_USERPWD` options in the request:

```
$curl = curl_init(); 
....
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC ) ; 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
```

In case you are using the `curl_setopt_array` function you can do something like that:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    ...
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => "username:password",
]);
```

Note that specifically in your code you were missing a space between `Basic` and the token.

Comment: $ch = curl_init('http://xxxxxxx:8080/LIMS_Mobile/rest/loginpage/authenticate');
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Authorization: Basic '.$authToken,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        ),
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($postData)
    )); i made this change and i got it. thanks for help. but could you please explain why did it work..!!